# Mongodb atlas failing to connect with Node Js ('ERR_SSL_TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR')

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, networking

I am trying to build a project using MONGO DB ATLAS, but as I'm trying to connect to the database I keep getting this error

```
 return new error_1.MongoNetworkError(error_1.MongoError.buildErrorMessage(err), { cause: err });
                   ^

MongoNetworkError: 640B0000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 80

    at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\ACER USER\Desktop\work\code\FRED_APP_AI_SERVER\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20) 
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ACER USER\Desktop\work\code\FRED_APP_AI_SERVER\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:285:22)  
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  connectionGeneration: 6,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
  [cause]: [Error: 640B0000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 80
  ] {
    library: 'SSL routines',
    reason: 'tlsv1 alert internal error',
    code: 'ERR_SSL_TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR'
  }
}
```

1. I've tried Whitelisting my IP address, it still doesn't work
2. I've crosschecked my MongoDB uri, it's correct but it's still not working

Comment: Based on the error it could be that your code tried TLS version 1 which is outdated and probably blocked by default. Maybe you need to update your SSL libraries or enable TLSv1 explicitly in settings in Atlas

Comment: how do i do that? @WernfriedDomscheit , how do i update my ssl libraries or enable TLSV1 in settings in Atlas

Comment: Maybe update your Node.js to latest version? Try also `npm update`